How to Filter Table by Max Value
I have the following table:
PRODUCT



LABEL
TRANSLATION
VALUE




Label1
Translate1
104


Label2
Translate2
102


Label3
Translate3
110



These values are pulling from another table based on matching product code.
I am trying to get it to return just the row with the highest value:
Label3       Translate3   110
I am trying to use filter by max in column 3, and I can see where the error says it is wrong, but i don't know another way to do it that fixes the error.
=IF(ISBLANK(F3), "", Filter({PRODUCT[LABEL], PRODUCT[TRANSLATION], PRODUCT[VALUE]}, MAX(PRODUCT[VALUE])))
It is giving me #N/A - FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 7. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.


You may try:
=filter(PRODUCT,PRODUCT[VALUE]=max(PRODUCT[VALUE]))



Use Filter or Query
You may use either:
Filter:
=LET(a,MAX(C2:C4),FILTER(A2:C4,C2:C4=a))

or Query:
=LET(a,MAX(C2:C4),QUERY(A1:C4,"SELECT * WHERE C = "&a,0))

Output:
Filter:

Query:


Use SORTN:
=SORTN(A2:C4,1,2,3,0)

